# Do I still have to pay airport fee in Lima?

Tags: airports, peru, fees-and-charges, lima

Six years ago, when I was leaving from Lima Jorge Chávez International Airport, there was airport fee of 30.25 USD. I had to pay this fee even If I already had the ticked (with Iberia, so normal, not a low-fare airline). Besides, the fee had to be paid in US dollars, not Peruvian soles.

Currently, would I still have to pay the airport fee? Or is it now included in ticket price? This was the only airport ever where I had to pay some extra fee, so I assume it's nowadays either already included in ticket price, or that's just the Peruvian regulations.

Comment: Happened to me in Vancouver as well in 2001

Comment: It isn't / wasn't just Peru; I've encountered separately collected "airport tax" or "departure tax" (of about 25 USD) in Cuba and Costa Rica.

Comment: Even in the UK, you need to pay GBP 10 at Blackpool airport (my least favourite airport) to get through security in departures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[When leaving Lima](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lima#Get_out)

> If you are flying out of Lima internationally, the airport tax is
>   US$31, US$7.40 for domestic flights. **As of January 2011 this tax has
>   been rolled into the purchase price of the tickets at this airport.**
>   Ensure you receive a sticker on the back of each ticket from the
>   check-in counter to attest to this at the security checkpoint.

Comment: Damn, how could I not see this link? My google-fu needs work.

Answer (score 4):

Most airlines have been collecting the airport tax (sometimes labeled *departure tax*, *embarkation tax* or *TUUA*) since October 2010 or January 2011, so you should already have paid for it when you bought your ticket.

This is at least the case with the main scheduled carriers (inc. Air Canada, American, Continental (now United), Delta, TACA, StarPerú, and LAN). The [LIM website](http://www.lap.com.pe/lap_portal/ingles/tuua.html) does advise double checking your with your airline.

Answer (score 2):

At Lima airport there is a sort of gate for this, with a few turnstiles attended by 2 or 3 Lima airport employees.

When I left Lima airport a few weeks ago, at this sort of gate an employee just scanned my boarding pass and told me to pass (without paying the fee). I was flying Iberia, in a LAN plane.

I am under the impression that nowadays at Lima airport the fee is usually included in ticket price.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Peru.  Since 2011, the tax has been added to the ticket price (as has long been practiced by American Airlines).  Once in a while, a travel agent will forget to add the TUUA and you will have to pay it at the airport; but this is very rare. 
So, there is a departure tax ($30.74 for international and $8.72 for domestic), but you shouldn't have to pay it in cash at the airport anymore.

Comment: What about people leaving the airport for some hours while waiting for their connection flight?

Answer (score 1):

Last time we went, 2 years ago, they even increased it to $80 per person (I think). It's a rip-off. We had a stop over. You go out, but when you come back they make you pay this ridiculous fee.

Comment: Annoying... I guess that since you weren't planned to leave and reenter, the storyline didn't pay the fee,and since you didn't check in at Lima,you didn't have the sticker.